# Möbius Band Bundle $(Mo,\mathbb{S}^1,\text{proj}_1,\mathbb{R}) $ is not a Principal $\mathbb{R}$-bundle

Tags: lie-groups, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, mobius-band

This is claimed in various places. The problem seems to be with finding a free and transitive group action that has the fibers of $Mo$ as its orbits. I construct $Mo$ as
$$ Mo = \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R} / \sim$$
where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation
$$ (t,x)  \sim (t+2\pi,-x).$$

I am new to this topic and don't see why it would be *impossible* to construct an action. $(R,+)$ is certainly a Lie group.

Comment: @tomasz Yes,  $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is also possible, but this construction is correct too. The absence of smooth sections is an obstruction to triviality of vector bundle, if I am not mistaken. The criterion for triviality of a principal bundle is existence of any global section, not neceserally nonzero. This is actually why I am asking, If $Mo$ was a principal bundle it would be trivial trough the zero section.

Comment: @tomasz  I am talking about a principal bundle. Not a vector bundle.

Comment: Alright, I somewhat misunderstood the question. I thought principal is just another name for trivial. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you are asking is: *why is a principal bundle with a global section trivializable?* Well, a principal bundle $G\to E\to B$ admits a free, transitive group action whose orbits are the fibers. If there is a principal section $s:B\to E$, then for every $b\in B$ we have $s(b)\in E$ and can map $g\to g\cdot s(b)$. This map provides a trivialization of $E$ by identifying 
$$e = g\cdot s(b) \leftrightarrow (g,b) $$
So you see, because the Mobius band has a global section --- the zero section --- if it admitted a free and transitive $\mathbb{R}$ action, that global section could be "smeared" into a trivialization. In this case, the $\mathbb{R}$ action must be *addition*, so to visualize this fact, ask yourself: if a rubber band is stretched around the core of a Mobius strip, can I roll it one centimeter off the core?

Comment: Should $s(b) \in E$ not be $s(b) \subset E$?

Comment: @TimonvanderBerg No: as $s:B\to E$, if $b\in B$, then the image of $b$ under $s$ will be an element of $E$, not a subset of $E$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you said it yourself, if $Mo$ would have the structure of a principal $\mathbf R$-bundle over $S^1$ then any global section of it would prove that it is trivial. Take the zero section $0$. It is a global section and would trivialize the principal bundle. Contradiction since the total space $Mo$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1\times\mathbf R$.

However, if you take out the image of the zero section, you get a total space $Mo^\star$, say, that does admit the structure of a principal $\mathbf R^\star$-bundle! And as such, it is a nontrivial principal $\mathbf R^\star$-bundle.

Comment: This is a correct proof, but it does not provide any insight as to *why* there is no group action. The facts you state are the reason for my question. I should have stated this in the question. :) Upvoted but not accepted.